# for loop to plot each 5 columns together

Tags: pandas, for-loop, plot

I have the following case:

```
df.iloc[:,1:6].plot(kind='box')
df.iloc[:,6:11].plot(kind='box')
df.iloc[:,11:16].plot(kind='box')
df.iloc[:,16:21].plot(kind='box')
df.iloc[:,21:26].plot(kind='box')
df.iloc[:,27:32].plot(kind='box')
df.iloc[:,33:38].plot(kind='box')
df.iloc[:,38:43].plot(kind='box')
df.iloc[:,43:48].plot(kind='box')
df.iloc[:,48:53].plot(kind='box')
```

I was trying to figure out the `for loop` for such case
Would that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
for i in range(1, df.shape[1]+1, 5):
    df.iloc[:,i:i+5].plot(kind='box')
```

*NB. this skips the first column, if you want to start from it:*

```
for i in range(0, df.shape[1], 5):
    df.iloc[:,i:i+5].plot(kind='box')
```

Comment: i have tried to implement this to plotly, it didn't work
i tried the following code:
`data=[]
for i in range(1,df_boxplot.shape[1]+1,5):
    data.append(go.Box(y = df_boxplot[i],
                       name = i,
                       showlegend = False))`
but it gave me an error
KeyError: 1

Comment: @ala It's impossible to help with just "it didn't work", you must provide a reproducible code and dataset that reproduces your issue. I suggest you open a new question with such a reproducible code

Comment: excuse me, i posted the comment by mistake so it was not completed yet

Comment: As I said, it would be much better to open a new question, don't forget to provide a reproducible dataset so that people can copy and run to reproduce your issue. Don't forget to ad the `plotly` tag in your new question.